# Set up Bluetooth (rfcomm) as a virtual serial port (dev/tty0)

Tags: usb, bluetooth, serial-port, bind

I have a bluetooth device that is discoverable through the command "hcitool scan".  Its protocol discriptor is "RFCOMM".  I can bind the device to the port rfcomm0 through the command

```
sudo rfcomm bind dev/rfcomm0 PORT NUMBER 1
```

However, the program I am interfacing with requires that the port the bluetooth is connected to is dev/ttyUSB0.  How can I bind my device to the port dev/ttyUSB0 or rename dev/rfcomm0 to dev/ttyUSB0.

I can't change the program requirements for the program I am interfacing with - so my bluetooth device has to be bound to the dev/ttyUSB0 port.

Also, my device cannot enter a PIN number - it is a simple EMG and all I can do with it is turn it on and off, there is no way to interface with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to bind rfcomm0 to ttyUSB0. The command is

```
sudo ln -s  /dev/rfcomm0 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

But it is advisible to not to use ttyUSB0 as it was commonly used, you can go with some generic names like ttyS99.

Comment: q5@q5-desktop:~$ sudo ln -s  /dev/rfcomm0 /dev/ttyUSB0
[sudo] password for q5: 
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/ttyUSB0': File exists
q5@q5-desktop:~$  Not so simple - see above

Comment: How can I use    "ln"  to DELETE linked files ?

Comment: can somebody help me to solve this?  I am back to the issue and still getting same error response 
[sudo] password for nov25-1: 
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/dev/ttyUSB0': File exists